# iOS: Search on a main word(noun), not its pronoun

Tags: search, ios4

I am writing a TableView app where people can search for a word in a foreign language. In this language, the article is important as it tells the word's gender.

A reasonable english example is "The Book".

I want to search for "Book", not "The".

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: If this were http://english.stackexchange.com/, I might mention that "the" is not a "pronoun", it's a "definite article"...

Comment: Fatigue, age, and other excuses welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about looking something up in a database, eg?  SQLite can be built with [Full Text Search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) extensions that allow you to search for individual words in text.  Even without the FTS extensions you can use a LIKE match in SQLite to find a word in a phrase, though the FTS extensions are much faster and more flexible.

You can also implement your own poor-man's Key Word In Context (KWIC) scheme -- basically just enter each item in the database N times for an N-word phrase, each time rotated one word.

And there are variations on the KWIC scheme that work for large numbers of phrases with less duplication -- using a tree structure to access the data.  With such approaches it's practical to implement a search without need for a keyboard, just by successively refining the table contents.

Answer (score 2):

You need a secondary index free from noise words and do a search against this. There are also some full text search libraries for iOS, or you can build your own version of Sqlite with full text module turned on.

Also you may consider preprocessing the query, for example using an algorithm to reduce it to its word root and then searching that with a wildcard (eg. 'consideration' >> 'consider*'

**Locatya** http://www.locayta.com/iOS-search-engine/locayta-search-mobile/register-for-download

**Building Sqlite with Fulltext on iOS** http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/06/16/sqlite-full-text-search-for-iphone-ipadyour-own-sqlite-for-iphone-and-ipad/

Comment: thanks Daniel, thanks CrunchyT.. I will look into each of these possibilities. I appreciate you both giving me leads.. This is a core data/sqlite database. People will be able to enter words, then look them up later. David